# Pattern rules with multiple parameters within a Makefile

Tags: makefile

```
%.600x.png: %.svg
    inkscape --export-png=$@ --export-width=600 --export-area-drawing $<

%.300x.png: %.svg
    inkscape --export-png=$@ --export-width=300 --export-area-drawing $<
```

How would you avoid the repetition shown in the above Makefile?  To get my point across, I'll invent some new syntax.

```
%(1).%(2)x.png: %(1).svg
    inkscape --export-png=$@ --export-width=%(2) --export-area-drawing $<
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive wildcard handling is one of Make's glaring shortcomings. Here is a way to do what you want, but it isn't exactly elegant:

```
define pngrule
%.$(1)x.png: %.svg
    inkscape --export-png=$$@ --export-width=$(1) --export-area-drawing $$<
endef

$(eval $(call pngrule,300))

$(eval $(call pngrule,600))
```

Note the `$$@` and `$$<` in the command, and the lack of whitespace in the `call` statements.

If you have a lot of these widths, it may be worthwhile to remove a little more redundancy:

```
WIDTHS := 300 600

$(foreach width,$(WIDTHS),$(eval $(call pngrule,$(width))))
```

Comment: While the shortcoming does bother me, it's not all bad in this case.  I don't completely mind having an easily enforced limited set of acceptable widths.

Comment: @altendky: If the wildcard handling were a little better, you could have a limited set of acceptable widths without so much plumbing. Questions equivalent to "how can I have more than one wildcard in a pattern rule?" come up a *lot*, and the answer is always clumsy.